# Quasi-regular element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring without unity. Let $x \in R$ be such that there exists a $y \in R$ with

$$-x-y+xy=0=-x-y+yx \hspace{0.1cm}.$$

I have to prove that $x$ in quasi-regular, i.e. there exists a $z \in R$ such that

$$x+z+xz=0=z+x+zx \hspace{0.1cm}.$$

Any ideas?

Comment: You mean "not necessarily having an identity" right? As a general rule, it is silly to prove statements for "rings having no identity."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't even true for rings with identity:

For example, in $\mathbb R$, with $x=-1$ you have $y=1/2$ satisfying $x+y=xy=yx$.

But you cannot find $z$ such that $-1+z=z$.

Now if you still want to shoehorn this into a ring with no identity, then you just take $S=(\mathbb R,+,\circ)$ where $\circ$ is zero for every product, and form the product ring $\mathbb R\times S$, and use $x'=(-1,0)$, $y'=(1/2,0)$ and show no $z'=(r_1,r_2)$ works.